# How do control start and stop of collection of Task Collection with non-blocking method in Worker Role

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, azure-worker-roles

I have the following in the OnStart method of a worker role:

```
// Loop through Port Mappings and start a listener for each mapping

foreach (var devicePortMapping in _listenConfig.DevicePortMappingCollection)
{
    Log.Information("Starting Listener for DeviceType {DeviceType} on {Port}", devicePortMapping.DeviceType,devicePortMapping.Port);

    _workerTasks.Add(
                    token =>
                    {
                        return
                            Task.Run(
                                () =>
                                {
                                    var listener = new InboundUdpListener(_container.Resolve<IMessagePublisher>(),
                                        devicePortMapping.DeviceType, devicePortMapping.Port);

                                    listener.Start();
                                }, token);
                    });
}
```

The start method is a void and kicks of a bunch of RX / Udp stuff but it's non-blocking.

I'm worried about what should be in my Run and OnStop methods to make sure it continues to run and that it shut's down gracefully.

In the consolidation pattern mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn589778.aspx is suggests using :

```
try
{
  Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
  Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);

  // If any of the inner exceptions in the aggregate exception 
  // are not cancellation exceptions then re-throw the exception.
  ex.Handle(innerEx => (innerEx is OperationCanceledException));
}
```

But surely this won't work as my Tasks will be complete as listener.start doesn't block ?

In the OnStop method is it sufficient to simply use:

```
_cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

I have complete control over the design of the functions here and maybe it's because I've been staring at this all day but I'm hoping someone might be able to give me some pointers, it seems to work but doesn't feel right.

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` instead of Task.WaitAny.  WaitAny will continue when the first task is finished.

Comment: You only want to use `_cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();` is when you need to force the tasks to cancel.  So yes, using it in OnStop is okay to stop gracefully.

Comment: OK, so that sounds good so far, I also have a Stop Method on the same UdpListener object which does a bunch of closing a unsubscribing etc and I'm wondering how I'd go about calling that ?

Comment: You call it when you are done listening. Not sure your workflow but you can use a destructor, IDisposable, when the user sends a cancel command, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I decided to refactor the design and push the marshalling of multiple udp listeners inside the listener class itself to simplify the control in the worker role itself.

Whenever I think might have grip on RX / Tasks / Async / Await something comes up which demonstrates I still have a ways to go.